# What is the point of using Gunicorn when hosting a Django project on Linux VM

Tags: python, django, linux, google-compute-engine, gunicorn

I have an Linux instance running on Google Compute Engine. I installed pip and django on it and cloned a Django project that I worked on locally. Like I would on localhost I ran my app like so: `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`, and my server was up and running with no problems. I read online on how WSGI servers are required for python apps to run well on servers however I don't see why I would need something like gunicorn to run my app

Comment: It's needed for concurrency and performance.

Comment: So django itself can run by itself, but gunicorn is just better at handling requests and performance, correct? @jordanm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what [the documentation for `runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver) says:

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Django's `runserver` is [itself a WSGI server](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e7b804c060a1f9fc089cf935801aa85b09db062b/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py#L24-L36), but it's aimed at being easy for developers to use.

Production WSGI servers like uWSGI and Gunicorn have performance and production environments in mind. They handle concurrency better, they are faster, and are built to withstand malicious users, not just developers.